# Resizing a iframe using @media rules

Tags: html, css, iframe, media-queries

I'm trying to resize a cbox iframe using media queries, so that it will resize when used by smaller screens. It just doesn't seem to be working, so any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

The HTML:

```
<div id="n-cbox"><iframe id="iframe-cbox" src="URL removed on purpose" height="404" allowtransparency="yes" allow="autoplay" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe></div>
```

CSS:

```
#n-cbox {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 218px;
    left: auto;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: auto;
    width: nullpx;
    padding: 0px;
}
        

#iframe-cbox {
    width:100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {

    #iframe-cbox {
        width:50%;
    }
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/jusotewuju/1/edit?output — I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: Maybe you just forgot the `}` at the end?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {

    #iframe-cbox {
        width:50% !important;
    }
}
```